# AngularJS/Sharepoint routing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I can't for the life of me get routing to work in SharePoint O365.  I'm sure it's just mt $routeProvider, I'm really unclear as to how to reference the html templateUrl's for Sharepoint.

Here's my app.js file.

```js
var app = angular.module("ClinicManagerApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "ClinicManager/views/home.htm",
        })
        .when("red", {
            templateUrl: "ClinicManager/views/red.htm",
        })
        .when("blue", {
            templateUrl: "ClinicManager/views/blue.htm",
        })
        .when("green", {
            templateUrl: "ClinicManager/views/green.htm",
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "ClinicManager/views/error.htm"
        })
});
```

The links to trigger the routing are as follows.

```html
<li><a href="ClinicManager/red">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="ClinicManager/blue">Blue</a></li>
<li><a href="ClinicManager/green">Green</a></li>
```

My folder structure is below

A document Library named "/DocLib"

```html
/DocLib/ClinicManager
:index.htm

/DobLib/ClinicManager/views
:blue.htm
:error.htm
:green.htm
:home.htm
:red.htm
```

The Red link's URL looks like this "mysharepointurl/DocLib/ClinicManager/red"

When I click any link, it'll take me to a "Page not found" page.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `/` before each name:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.htm",
        })
        .when("/red", {
            templateUrl: "views/red.htm",
        })
        .when("/blue", {
            templateUrl: "views/blue.htm",
        })
        .when("/green", {
            templateUrl: "views/green.htm",
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "views/error.htm"
        })
});
```

also add `#` in href:

```
<li><a href="#ClinicManager/red">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="#ClinicManager/blue">Blue</a></li>
<li><a href="#ClinicManager/green">Green</a></li>
```

Here is example how routing should look like: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/sCeIL7y6jCf3Cv72

Comment: Eureka!!  Although I had to add
.when("/", { templateUrl: "ClinicManager/views/home.htm"})
to the $routeProvider.